# Can not get shortcode content in function

Tags: shortcode, page-template

I use a shortcode on my page like

```
[homepage_featuredproducts]test[/homepage_featuredproducts]
```

In my functions.php

```
function homepage_featuredproducts( $atts , $content = null ) {
  if('{{emtpy}}'!=$content) $content='empty';
  return $content;

}
add_shortcode( 'homepage_featuredproducts', 'homepage_featuredproducts' );
```

And in my template somewhere

```
<p><?php echo do_shortcode( '[homepage_featuredproducts]' ) ?></p>
```

And it allways returns "empty".

Why cant I get the content between the shortcodes in my function and return it?

Comment: var_dump($content) gives me string(0) ""

Comment: Of course it will return "empty" - remove the `if` line in your shortcode handler.

Answer (score -1):

```
function homepage_featuredproducts( $atts , $content = null ) {
  if( empty( $content ) ) 
     $content='no content to display';

  return $content;

}
add_shortcode( 'homepage_featuredproducts', 'homepage_featuredproducts' );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?